# Python telegram bot 2 or more arguments

Tags: python, arguments, telegram

I have python telegram-bot and try to search table for 2 columns.

How to make bot accept 2 arguments, right now if I use /char 1 2 (or /char 1 2 3 4 5 etc will send 5 query results for every level).

It sends me 2 different messages, one with Character lvl 1 and second with Character level 2.

But I would like to search from DB for example: "Class and Level" /char warrior 1

```
WHERE Class='arg1' and level='arg2'
```

Or maybe is possible to put results into a string and read from there, just that bot read next argument as new command.

Thanks.

```
/char 3 1

[Character] [Class] [Level]
["Char6","tank",3]

[Character] [Class] [Level]
["Char1","warrior",1]
```

```
def char(bot, update,args):
  for arg in args:
       print(arg)
       cursor.execute("SELECT name,Class,level users where level="+arg)
       row = cursor.fetchone()
       if row == None:
           chat_id = update.message.chat_id
           bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=('No Character found '+arg))

       else:
           data = row[0],row[1],row[2]
           print(data)
           #cursor.close()
           #conn.close()
           chat_id = update.message.chat_id
           bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=('[Character] [Class] [Level]'))
           bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=(data))
```

Comment: So far found a workaround if send arguments with comma like
```/char Char1,1```
and from string I split arguments
```arg1=arg.split(',')[0]
    arg2=arg.split(',')[1]```

Still can't get the string from "arg" as ```Char1 1```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to answer my own question, it's easy to do it in the end.

```
def char(update, context):
    create=update.message.text[6:] #6 because your command is /char (+space) = 6 chars
    create = create.split()        #create split
    Class = create[0]              #first from split is class to search
    Level= create[1]               #second for level
```